# Strange output for a simple OpenMP program on Multi2sim v4.0.1

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openmp

I'm trying to run a simple program using OpenMP

the program is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define NUM 10



void openMP()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    int sum =0;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"sum = "<<sum<<endl;

}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Open MP \n";
    openMP();
return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile it using

`g++ test.cpp -fopenmp -o test`

and run it on ubuntu terminal

`./test`

the output is correct - I think - as follows

```
Open MP 
sum = 100
```

But when I try to run it using Multi2sim using these 2 files I was given by my instructor

multicore-config:

```
[ General ]
Cores = 4
Threads = 1
```

multicore-mem-config:

```
[CacheGeometry geo-l1]
Sets = 256
Assoc = 2
BlockSize = 64
Latency = 2
Policy = LRU
Ports = 2

[CacheGeometry geo-l2]
Sets = 512
Assoc = 4
BlockSize = 64
Latency = 20
Policy = LRU
Ports = 4

[Module mod-l1-0]
Type = Cache
Geometry = geo-l1
LowNetwork = net-l1-l2 
LowModules = mod-l2

[Module mod-l1-1]
Type = Cache
Geometry = geo-l1
LowNetwork = net-l1-l2 
LowModules = mod-l2

[Module mod-l2]
Type = Cache
Geometry = geo-l2
HighNetwork = net-l1-l2 
LowNetwork = net-l2-mm
LowModules = mod-mm

[Module mod-mm]
Type = MainMemory
BlockSize = 256
Latency = 200
HighNetwork = net-l2-mm

[Network net-l2-mm]
DefaultInputBufferSize = 1024 
DefaultOutputBufferSize = 1024
DefaultBandwidth = 256 

[Network net-l1-l2]
DefaultInputBufferSize = 1024 
DefaultOutputBufferSize = 1024
DefaultBandwidth = 256 

[Entry core-0]
Arch = x86
Core = 0
Thread = 0
DataModule = mod-l1-0
InstModule = mod-l1-0

[Entry core-1]
Arch = x86
Core = 1
Thread = 0
DataModule = mod-l1-0
InstModule = mod-l1-0

[Entry core-2]
Arch = x86
Core = 2
Thread = 0
DataModule = mod-l1-0
InstModule = mod-l1-0

[Entry core-3]
Arch = x86
Core = 3
Thread = 0
DataModule = mod-l1-0
InstModule = mod-l1-0
```

And then using this instruction in Ubuntu terminal

```
m2s --x86-config multicore-config.txt --mem-config multicore-mem-config.txt --x86-sim detailed test
```

I get the output

```
; Multi2Sim 4.0.1 - A Simulation Framework for CPU-GPU Heterogeneous Computing
; Please use command 'm2s --help' for a list of command-line options.
; Last compilation: May  8 2013 10:01:31

Open MP 
sum = 83

;
; Simulation Statistics Summary
;

[ General ]
Time = 53.17
SimEnd = ContextsFinished
Cycles = 3691870

[ x86 ]
SimType = Detailed
Time = 53.15
Contexts = 4
Memory = 37056512
EmulatedInstructions = 3292450
EmulatedInstructionsPerSecond = 61943
Cycles = 3691558
CyclesPerSecond = 69452
FastForwardInstructions = 0
CommittedInstructions = 2081157
CommittedInstructionsPerCycle = 0.5638
CommittedMicroInstructions = 3113721
CommittedMicroInstructionsPerCycle = 0.8435
BranchPredictionAccuracy = 0.9375
```

why is the output in Multi2sim `83` while the output in a normal run is `100`

Also why does it take so much time to run on Multi2Sim ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know `m2s`, but it could be the case that the culprit is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            sum++; // Concurrent access to a shared variable!!!
        }
    }
```

In your first test the fact that you explicitly set the number of threads to `1`:

```
omp_set_num_threads(1);
```

saves you from race conditions. I would suggest trying with:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum) reduction(+:sum)
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            sum++;
}
```

to see if you can obtain the desired behavior.

Comment: No, it didn't help with the problem I have.. As far as I know m2s creates an environment for this program to run on an emulator and it should simulate this code for a processor with 4 cores and one thread.

Can you tell me more about `reduction`?

Comment: After testing somethings again reduction did in fact work. Thank you.